# Devise error messages missing after custom redirect

Tags: forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a custom redirects in place for my devise sign up forms, I have two forms, one for an individual and another for a company. I have added this in the create action of the registrations controller:

```
if resource.company_form
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path(company: true)    
  else  
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path
  end
```

In doing this though I have lost all the devise error messages, as in the don't display any validation errors, so I need to send the error messages along with the redirect, don't I? However, I am not sure how.

So far I have tried printing the error messages to the console:

```
ap(resource.errors.full_messages)

[
 [0] "Email can't be blank",
 [1] "Password can't be blank",
 [2] "Company name can't be blank"
]
```

Whereas this:

```
ap(resource.errors)

@messages={:email=>["can't be blank"], :password=>["can't be blank"], :company_name=>["can't be blank"]}
```

How would I get the error messages to be displayed above the form again?

Answer (score 1):

The magic of devise error messages is made with respond_with method.

Hence you can change the redirect_to for a respond_with block

```
respond_with(resource) do |format|
  if resource.company_form
    format.html { render 'new', locals: { is_organisation: true } }
  else  
    format.html { render 'new' }
  end
end
```

and in your view

```
<% params[:organisation] ||= is_organisation -%>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but im still getting no error messages displayed

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe flash messages are not sent in the redirect_to directive

Comment: im not quite sure how that would go in my view sorry

Comment: instead of 'new', you can put your template path

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but you can customize this even further with your messages. First things first it's a good idea to actually ensure this works first. Then customize it further.

1. Add your toastr gem to your gemfile.

`gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0'`

2. In your application.js you will need to add `//= require toastr`
3. In your stylesheet.scss you will need to import toastr `@import "toastr";`
4. Then run `bundle` in your terminal

In your views/devise/registrations/ folder and `views/devise/password/` folder, the pages inside are your devise views that show the error messages. There you will find the error messages by devise. `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`

So what you wanna do, is customize these messages.

Now go to views/shared and create a new file and name it `_devisemes.html.erb`

```
<% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |value| %>
     toastr.error('<%= value %>')
   <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

After you have saved this file. Just go to the following files and find

**`<%= devise_error_messages! %>`**

Replace it with **`<%= render 'shared/devisemes' %>`** in the following files below:

`views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`

`views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

`views/devise/password/new.html.erb`

`views/devise/password/edit.html.erb`

Now logout and go to create an account and without an email, or password and test it. You will notice all the error messages from devise showing up with toastr.